# PHP not sending contact form to email address

Tags: php

I have been using this formmail.php file for the past couple months and have not had a problem with receiving e-mails once a user hits submit. Now, when I hit submit, it goes through the process of going to the thanks.html page, but I never receive an email. Any suggestions will be greatly appreciated

Here is the form I have:

```
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="php/formmail.php">
  <label>
    <input name="name" type="text" id="name" size="68" value="full name / e-mail">
  </label>
  <label>
    <input name="Submit" type="submit" value="Submit" id="submit">
  </label>
</form>
```

Here is the code I have for the formmail.php:

```
<?php
    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=="POST"){
        // In testing, if you get an Bad referer error
        // comment out or remove the next three lines
        /*if (strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'], $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'])>7 ||
        !strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'], $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']))
            die("Bad referer");*/
        $msg="Versed Media LLC"; //This message will be in the body of your email.
        foreach($_POST as $key => $val){
            if (is_array($val)){
                $msg.="Item: $key\n\n";
                foreach($val as $v){
                    $v = stripslashes($v);
                    $msg.="   $v\n\n";
                }
            } else {
                $val = stripslashes($val);
                $msg.="$key: $val\n\n";
            }
        }
        $recipient="dezingeek@gmail.com"; // your email address goes here, or the email of who    the form should be sent to.
        $subject="E-Mailing List"; //The subject of the email goes here.
        error_reporting(0);
        if (mail($recipient, $subject, $msg)){
            header( "Location: thanks.html" ); //This should be the link to the thank you page.
        } else{
            echo "An error occurred and the message could not be sent.";
        }
    } else{
        echo "Bad request method";
    }
?>
```

Comment: Nothing wrong with your code. Check your logs and/or Spam. You're also missing a `From:` which may send it to Spam or reject it altogether. Consult the manual http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php

Comment: Try to add the 4th parameter to the mail command. May be your hosting provider now denied sending mail without headers. You must add a From header. Maybe it's the problem. Else, ask directly your hosting provider, your code is good.

Comment: Did you check your server php.ini? you may have the mail function disabled.

Comment: Does the version oh PHP matter? When I check my control panel it says I am running Linux / Apache / PHP 5.3. It also gives me the options to change it to:
(1) Linux / Apache / PHP 5.4
(2) Windows Server 2008 / llS 7 / .Net 2.0, 3.0, 3.5
(3) Windows Server 2008 / llS 7 / .Net 4.0
(4) Windows Server 2012 R2 / llS 8.5 / .Net 4.5

Answer (score 0):

if previously your code works fine, then check if is your server is change or mail function works properly or not

First you just check your simple mail function works or not, if not then contact your server host manager.
Check that your mail function is not disabled in your php.ini